# Ionic <ion-item> between <ion-label> and <ion-datetime> not showing up

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to make content appear between a stacked ion-label and ion-datetime input, but it just doesn't show up. What am I doing wrong? This is the html code:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label stacked >
    <p>Test label</p>
  </ion-label>
  <ion-item>
    <img src="https://www.shorturl.at/img/shorturl-square.png" />
    <p class="multiline-text"> Test text </p>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-datetime displayFormat="MMM D, YYYY" placeholder="MMM D, YYYY"></ion-datetime>
  <button large class="transparent-button" style="align-self: flex-start; margin-top:12px;" ion-button item-right (click)="toggleHelp(input)">
    <ion-icon style="font-size: 1.7em; align-self: flex-start;" name="ios-help-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
  </button>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: `<ion-item>` is of that annoying tags! Don't try using it like `<div>` or you'll get heavily unexpected things! And plus, don't use it nested with another of the same tag, as you don't get the result you want.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is your expected output?

Comment: imans77 - Unfortunately, using divs instead of ion-item doesn't help.

Comment: Mystery - I expect the image and paragraph elements to show up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a while of digging through Google searches I found that *item-content* attribute has to be added to the ion-item. This code works:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label stacked >
    <p>Test label</p>
  </ion-label>
  <ion-item item-content>
    <img src="https://www.shorturl.at/img/shorturl-square.png" />
    <p class="multiline-text"> Test text </p>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-datetime displayFormat="MMM D, YYYY" placeholder="MMM D, YYYY"></ion-datetime>
  <button large class="transparent-button" style="align-self: flex-start; margin-top:12px;" ion-button item-right (click)="toggleHelp(input)">
    <ion-icon style="font-size: 1.7em; align-self: flex-start;" name="ios-help-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
  </button>
</ion-item>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-cmkons?file=pages/home/home.html

Answer (score 0):

I copied and tested your code in one of my projects and the content appears.

The first thing I noticed is you have an ion-item nested inside another ion-item.  You should close an ion-item before proceeding to next ion-item.  I would suggest using custom css to build what you are trying to achieve, instead of using ionic UI Components in ways not really intended.

Comment: Weird, not showing up for me even when using div tags... https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-txb3di?file=pages/home/home.html